# Password issue in wordpress login

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I  forgot my wordpress admin password of my site run in local host.So to create a new password i opened database and  wp_user  table.Here under my password field i type new password (new passsword is 'admin') and change the Function as **md5** and save it .so user password change to   **21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3**

But i cannot login using typing admin as password in login window.

when i am typing user name and password then enter it result the same login window appear again and the user password in the table automatically changed to **$P$BM8FIAcMUDBQcDz8tF37LMTVt2H.Ef.**

how can i fix these issue and login to admin panel . I need support from all of you that know how to fix these issue.. Thanks

Comment: This question is off topic on SO, it would be more suited on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Go into PhpMyAdmin it might vary depending on configurations. Look for the database name on the left sidebar. In our case it’s called “wordpress“.

Click “wordpress“ to see its tables. Look for *_users, in our case it’s called wp1_users. Click it and you’ll notice a page change on the right frame. user_login column shows you all usernames you currently have. If you are looking for usernames, your problem is solved. But if you are looking to recover lost password, there is one more thing you’ll need to do.

Click on the pen icon to edit the data for the specific user. Look for “user_pass” field. Select "MD5" for the Function dropdown, and change it’s value to a new password, in our case the new password is call “admin“. Click GO once you are done.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done to change the admin password is correct method. But make sure you are putting the right user/password without any blank spaces, Though it does not looks like that might be the issue, So i think there is some sort of security plugin installed with wordpress which you will have to disable from the command shell. Just change the permission of the security plugin and give a try.  Hopefully it works out.